# SIGABRT error and application crashing

Tags: iphone

This is my code from where i am getting `SIGABRT error`

```
p3=@"0123456789";
[password appendFormat: @"%C", [p3 characterAtIndex: arc4random() % [p3 length]]];
```

How to resolve this

Comment: what is password ? NSString ?

Comment: Is this Mac OSX app? coz arc4random() is in Mac OSX library.!

Comment: Ok it sees from ur comment that it is iOS app. but whts that `arc4random()`? why do u use that?

Comment: i want to generate random characters from string p3

Answer (score 0):

```
p3=@"0123456789";
[password appendFormat: @"%C", [p3 characterAtIndex: arc4random() % ([p3 length]-1])];
```

It seems that you are going out of the bounds of the array of index, the start from 0. Ad the -1.

Answer (score 0):

when the random number is 0, the index will be length of string, which is out of limit. so jst use one less of length as `index =  arc4random() % ([str length]-1;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    NSString *p3=@"0123456789"; 
    int t = arc4random() % [p3 length];
    NSLog(@"%@",[p3 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(t, 1)]);

    NSMutableString * password = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [password appendFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[p3 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(t, 1)]]];
```